# What is the name of this psychological effect?

Tags: psychoacoustics

What's the name of the following effect, so that I can find out more about it: If we cut a song into small chunks (~50ms) and invert each one, our brain is still able to recognize the song instead of hearing a huge mess. I've just tried it in my DAW and it really works. We don't hear a perfect reconstruction, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is no name as such, but it would fall into the category of psychoacoustics.

Comment: Any idea how to google it? I can't remember where I heard that and I'm not finding anything.

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=psychoacoustics

:-)

Comment: I mean, the effect in specifics, I was expecting a lmgfy, but maybe a more useful one. My google skills are not that bad :p

Comment: If I run that search I get a load of interesting stuff from Fraunhofer institute and others - loads there

Comment: Indeed, but not exactly the phenomenon I mentioned. Anyway, I found something in the audio here: https://www.nsf.gov/news/mmg/mmg_disp.jsp?med_id=78672  from around 22:00 to 24:00. Perhaps it would have been more suitable to another stack.